# How to generate Entity Relationship diagram of Core data xcdatamodel

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship, diagram, erd

I was wondering whether is there any way to generate the Entity Relationship Diagram (that contains entities and their relationship) of Core Data using xcdatamodel Or any other class of Core data.

If there is anyway then please tell.

Comment: The closest thing there is built-in support is Xcode's diagram view of the model.

Answer (score 3):

**Step:**

1. First open the `XYZ.xcdatamodeld` file.
2. Can you see the bottom-right option named as `Editor Style`.
3. Tweak it to the graph like relationship mode.

[image]

Comment: Did you find anything which serve your purpose ?

Comment: Apple decided to remove this view from xcode 14: [Xcode 14 Beta 3 Core Data Model Editor Style](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710008).